# how to stop interval in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using rxjs6 interval in my angular6 application.Following is my code to implement interval in angular6 app.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
const source = interval(1000);
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

everything works fine, but how can I stop this interval ?.When I tried with unsubscribe angular says that `source.unsubscribe is not a function`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to call `unsubscribe()` on the `subscribe` variable.

```
//emit value in sequence every 1 second
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5....
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
setTimeout(()=> subscribe.unsubscribe(), 2000);
```

see here: http://jsbin.com/kajenif/1/edit?js,console,output

here's a good tip from rxjs lead: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87